# How to NOT find something in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, string, find

EDIT :
ok, sorry for not so clear question. Let's try other way:
We have an ArayList of names : Peter, John, Adam

We are looking for String name;
If ArrayList contains the String, we want to write the String. If ArrayList doesn't contains the String, we want to add the String into the ArrayList.

If I'm looking for "Adam", then this program is not working, because first it finds name "Peter", then "John", and only after that it finds "Adam". So for the first 2 times, it thinks, "Adam" is not in the list, and acts so.

```
String findName;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  if (arrayList.get(i).getValue().contains(findName)) {
    System.out.println(findName);
    break;
  }
  else 
   arrayList.add(findString);
 }
```

Original question :

I have a String and an Array (ArrayList). I have to do something, if the String is in the Array and something else, if it is not in the Array. How do I do that?
I can't do it like this :

```
String myString;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  if (arrayList.get(i).getValue().equals(myString)) {
    DO SOMETHING;
    break;
  }
  else
   DO SOMETHING ELSE;
 }
```

because it will find the String only once and all the other times it will act, like the arraylist doesn't contains the String.

So I'm doing it like this :

```
String findString = "0";
String myString;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  if (arrayList.get(i).getValue().equals(myString)) {
    DO SOMETHING;
    findString = "2";  //when I find the String, I change this
    break;
  }
  if findString == "0";  //if I have not found the String, this happens
   DO SOMETHING ELSE;
 }
```

and I have the feeling, it should be not done like this. ;)

I know I can use booleans instead of this way, but it's the same in other way. Isn't there total different way of doing this correctly?

Comment: Remove the break statement

Comment: `equals(String)` instead of `==`

Comment: Do you want to do the "do something" for EVERY match in the array? If so, then you CAN'T `break`, because break will terminate the loop. And you can't do the "something else" until AFTER the loop finishes, because you'll never know if the string will show up later on in the loop or not. e.g. you're basically doing "did I run over something in the car in the last 30 seconds? NOpe. Ok. I probably won't run over anything else in the next 10 hours either".

Comment: Can you phrase it in one clear, concise question? You want to do something if it's contained in both the array and list?

Comment: so you're looking through an array list of strings right? if i have the string "There", should you DO SOMETHING if you're searching for the string "here"? or do the two strings have to be exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way is as follows: Declare a method which returns whether the string is in the array:

```
public boolean arrContainsStr(String str, String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use this method in your code like this:

```
String myString;    
String[] myArray;
if (arrContainsStr(myString, myArray)) {
    DO SOMETHING;
}else {
    DO SOMETHING ELSE;
}
```

This is for primitive string arrays. Note that if you are using an `ArrayList` or similar, you can simply use the `.contains(myString)` method to check if the list contains your string. Documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit odd, but just reading your first sentence, if you want to see if a `List` e.g. `ArrayList` contains an object (e.g. a `String`) you can just use the `contains(Object o)` method rather than looping through. I must be missing your point. In any case, an example:

```
String stringToFind = "Foo";
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("Foo");
if (stringList.contains(stringToFind)) {
    System.out.println("String found");
} else {
    System.out.println("String not found");
}
```

Output: String found. (In this example).

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use `.contains` as below to check if the String is in the list?

```
if(arrayList.contains(myString)){
    // DO SOMETHING
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean to true if you find your value then break.
If you don't find the value, the boolean will stay to false.
Then you do the if

Answer (score 0):

Its a little vague so I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you remove the break in the first segment of code i think you will get what you want. do you want it do DO SOMETHING for every occurrence of the string or just the first one. also if you do need the break you could check the value of i after the loop terminates so

```
if(i==arrayList.size())
{
    //String found
}
else 
{
    //String not found
}
```

Comment: also you need the break in the loop if you want to use i as the test variable